# Is it possible install Photoshop on elementary OS?

Tags: software-installation

I've installed elementary OS on my pc and I need of PhotoShop (I like create layout site with PhotoShop). Can I install PhotoShop on elementary OS without virtual box?

Comment: please refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/530110/how-can-i-install-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Try using WINE to install it.You can find guides all over the internet

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop is a windows/mac program for which no linux version is available. However it might be possible to run it using wine. According to the [wine appdb](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32438&iTestingId=90146) other people have tried and had mixed results with it.

An alternative could be using [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) for which a linux version is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Photoshop CS6 on elementaryOS with PlayOnLinux : https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2316-Adobe_Photoshop_CS6.html

First install PlayOnLinux https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html#pres_item6, follow the instructions in the Ubuntu Trusty Category.

Then open PlayOnLinux and click the button "Install", then search for "photoshop" and follow the instructions !

Screens from my computer :

[image: Photoshop on Linux]

[image: PlayOnLinux with Windows softwares]